# Access Mega Cloud Storage from File Manager on a non rooted device

Tags: storage, mount, termux, cloud

Is there a way to mount Mega cloud storage from file manager. Mega has some option to do that as Webdav Server for Desktops but is there a way Android Phone with TLS encryption. I am even comfortable with using CLI on Termux. It would be even enough if I can make that available in termux. I am trying this because I have less storage in my device.

Comment: Looks like MEGA has [their own mobile apps](https://mega.io/mobile), any reason why it can't be used? Otherwise, they force you to use [their MEGA SDK for C++](https://mega.io/doc) (no other languages available).

Comment: Yes the do have an app. But I can't access my files from file manager. I am trying this because I am running out of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to have your Mega cloud in the file-picker/file-manager (and any related Storage Access Framework).

The point is, since your device is not rooted you cannot mount the cloud directly in your system.

Therefore, what I recommend is to use the [RCX app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.x0b.rcx): thanks to it, you'll be able to acces any "Rclone's cloud" (Mega, GDrive, MSDrive, ...) by using SAF (once set, you will see you Mega cloud like you would see an USB stick).

You will be able to pick files from you Mega cloud within Termux by using `termux-storage-get`, but you will need to install Termux-API first.

If you really want to stay with Termux (and don't want to install RCX app), you can also just install rclone in Termux, set your Mega account, and access it using `rclone tree remoteName:`. But your cloud will be only available in Termux.